# ExtJS 4 - grid grouping expand/collpase only certain groups

Tags: extjs, view, grid, extjs4, grouping

From the API there is a config flag that one can set to expand or collapse grid groupings when rendered.

Is there a way to only expand the first grouping and have all the others collapsed?

For example i have a store with up to three groupings and would like to always have the first grouping expanded and the others collapsed.

there does not seem to be an easy way from the API to be able to do this!

Comment: @RyanP13.....I have searched for this in Ext doc but there is nothing related to only expand the first grouping and have all the others collapsed. So, you have to implement this on event of `store` or `grid`. [expand()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping-method-expand) method may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to program it!
But it isn't difficult... Look at the official Sencha examples, there you find a [grouping](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/grid/groupgrid.html) example!

You will have to do following:

```
 //Either this...       
groupingFeature.expand(groupName, true);

//or this...
groupingFeature.collapse(groupName, true);
```

You should place the commands in an *afterrender* event of the grid. 
Or you try the *groupchange* event from the store (I am not sure if it is called on the init-process)

For the grid it should look like this...

```
afterrender:( grid, eOpts ) {
    var groupingFeature = grid.getView().features[0];

    groupingFeature.expand(groupName, true);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

user1934574's answer has a little problem. You should **get the view of the grid** and then get the features.
The code should be :

```
afterrender:( grid, eOpts ) {
    var groupingFeature = grid.getView().features[0]; 

    groupingFeature.expand(groupName, true);
    ...
}
```